# How to open only gallery app for images in Android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I searched a lot on SO and on google.

But I couldn't get a answer.

I am using `samsung galaxy-s3 (v 4.3)`.

That's why this question.

I tried to open gallery using this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
i.putExtra("crop", "true");
i.putExtra("outputX", 400);
i.putExtra("outputY", 400);
i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
i.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
i.putExtra("scale", true);
i.putExtra("return-data", true);

startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
```

But android system pops-up with the system "Gallery" and "Photos"(from google plus app).

Is there any way to show only the gallery app.

Similarly, while cropping two options are displaying. 
If user selects "Crop photo", then app doesnt get the selected image.

I want to show only gallery images with crop option.

Comment: If you want to crop an image, use a library. If you want to pick a photo, please allow the *user* to choose what app the *user* wants in order to pick the photo.

Comment: Hi Mark, actually client don't want any other app to pop-up. Only gallery images should pop-up. So what is in my mind is, get all the images from mediastore content provider and display as grid view. Is there any other better option. That is what I was searching

Comment: Thanks commonsware and vivekH. I found the answer. What I did was, a combination of Commonsware and vivekH answer. First I pass the intent,

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

to queryIntentActivities of PackageManager. Then I got a list of activities, from that I opened gallery and in the onActivityResult, got the selected image. I cropped the selected image using open source lib. https://github.com/biokys/cropimage . This I got from http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html